# Issue with percent encoding in paperclip document.url on s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I just upgraded my gems and paperclip urls are now encoded properly with `%3F` for the `?` that Amazon likes to use. However, this breaks the links for my users when doing:

```
<a href="<%= client.document.url %>">Link</a>
```

Right now I'm manually replacing the %3F with a ? by using gsub, but am wondering whether there is something wrong in my code instead of in the gems or on Amazon's side. My fix:

```
<%= client.document.url.gsub(/%3F/, "?") %>
```

Is there something else I could be doing or should know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`URI.unescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape):

```
<%= URI.unescape(client.document.url) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Paperclip 4.2.1 (see issues [#1706](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1706) and [#1732](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1732)) - `?` in urls are escaped to `%3F` when they should not be.

The options are to pin Paperclip to version 4.2.0 (`gem 'paperclip', '4.2.0'`), or temporarily disable timestamping of urls:

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```

The bug was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/804b4edc1d8d7ca9865170e34f26da7d66f6d0d5).

Comment: Or `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:escape_url] = false` if you want/need cache busting.